# Why does python subprocess.Popen launch a subprocess through cmd.exe?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I call subprocess like this:

```
command = 'c:\somepath\myexe.exe'

startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

It appears that instead of launching myexe.exe directly, it goes through cmd.exe.  Can I avoid cmd.exe here?

Comment: What makes you think it uses `cmd`?  It most certainly doesn't.

Comment: You mean `|=` there rather than `!=`. One is "bitwise or" assignment one is "not equals" comparison.

Comment: for each myexe.exe that appears in the process list is see a cmd.exe show under csrss.exe.  can't be a coincidence, its one for one.

Comment: You are probably seeing the cmd process that launched the python script.

Comment: I just had a look at the source code.   The Python part only looks up `cmd.exe` if `shell=True` [(1)](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/554802e562fa/Lib/subprocess.py#l866) and the C part directly uses `CreateProcess()` to spawn the process [(2)](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/554802e562fa/PC/_subprocess.c#l411).

Comment: Which versions of Windows and Python are you using?

Comment: I am launching my myexe.exe one after another.  And I see one cmd.exe launch for each myexe.exe.  Python 2.6.6 here.  Hmmm.

Comment: Well, if that's all you're doing, it's not Python's fault. Perhaps myexe.exe is doing it. [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) is helpful for seeing the process tree. Try looking at it while you're running your script.

Answer (score 3):

Iff you're using Python 2.7 - use subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW instead of subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW. I think this would solve it.